# Moving Div and Content into Another Div

Tags: javascript

I have tried to move my div and its contents to another div using such things as:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('#header').appendChild(
    document.getElementById('#live')
  );
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$("#header").append($("#live"))

  );
</script>
```

but i cant move the div the best i have done is move some text about.

Help.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript _au naturel_ or is jQuery or another JavaScript library part of your application?

Comment: Firstly, you need to give us some context (used HTML etc). Secondly, when calling `document.getElementById` you don't need the # in the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, the code you want is

```
$('#div1Content').appendTo('#div2');
```

Have a look here for a demo,
http://jsfiddle.net/nwe44/we2cN/

Comment: Successes, sort of ,I now have it working using the code from the link, so you need to click the link, is there a way to do this on load, so it happens straight away. Thanks Very much

Comment: If you do it onload the user will see a jump, as the page may render before JavaScript gets a chance to look at it, so I'd advise against, although obviously I have no context for this recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#live').appendTo('#header');
```

alternatively,

```
var live = $('#live').detach();
//do stuff
live.appendTo('#header');
```

detach() removes it from the DOM but keeps it in memory, then you can append it to its new parent.

Comment: You don't need to `detach` it first. Just `appendTo` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for feed back I will try your suggestion and get back right now thanks

Comment: Im using javascript I am having to but a div in the footer that needto go in the header, I can not get at the code for the whole site only the foot html.

Comment: @dave If by header you mean the head of the page then you can get a reference using just, $('head'). The '#' indicates that the following word is the id of an element in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery (as you appear to be using it in one of your examples) you can use the `appendTo` method (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo)):

```
$("#live").appendTo("#header");
```

This moves the `#live` element into the `#header` element.

Comment: I will explain a little more I have a div with some other javascript in it, it is in the footer, I wish it to be at the top of the page eg in header (not top of viewport) not to stay visable when scrolling but to scroll up as in normal flow, I cant get access to the full html to put the div in the right place so need javascript to come to my resuce but can get it working. Site is using jquery 1.4. and jquery-ui 1.8